Should you normalize binary predictors in linear regression?
I have a linear regression y=ax+c and a multiple regression y=ax+bz+c. In both x is a binary variable (0,1). y has been covariate corrected and normalized. Should x be normalized too?

Normalize x only if you want to make the interpretation more difficult.  Avoid multi-step procedures; analyze raw y and adjust for other covariates while modeling x.

All right thanks. Why should I analyze raw y instead of using the residuals? Why do people often regress out covariates + normalize, instead of using raw values and covariates in same equation?

They must be looking for ways to spend extra time :-) and they forget that some models like logistic regression don’t even have residuals.
